# eccentricity of the conic

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I'm given this question to find the eccentricity of this conic : $x^2 + ky = 0, k>0$

The given equation can be written as $x^2 = -ky$ now we can say compare this with the equation of parabola.
But the eccentricity of the parabola is $1$

Now I'm given two options for this question out of which none of them is $1$

Options are $A. \frac{1}{k + 1}$

```
                  B.  eccentricity lies between $0$ and $1$
```

Option B. suits for equation of ellipse but the given equation is in no way equation of ellipse.

I'm confused. Kindly help me clarify this.

Comment: Between is ambiguous. It might allow 0,1, or not. But A is clearly wrong.

Comment: @almagest but B. is also not slightly possible because this is clearly an equation of parabola and eccentricity of parabola is $1$.